# Rstudio Installation on Ubuntu App windows 11 I get Black screen

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Rstudio from terminal of Ubuntu App of windows 11 (Windows subsystem for linux)
R version is R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
R studio after installation

1. wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-2022.02.2-485-amd64.deb
2. sudo dpkg -i rstudio-2022.02.2-485-amd64.deb
3. sudo apt install -f
4. Then started rstudio (the menu above also flickers)

But I get like this  [image: The screen I see when I open rstudio]

I am new to linux and R but I need to learn it for my course please if someone can help as i need to use R in linux

If I have to change any please help with steps i did all search in google everywhere didnt get solution please help

Comment: You need to learn R-on-linux-in-wsl for the course, or you need to learn R? If you're using wsl, is there a reason you're not using native-windows RStudio?

Comment: As i am undergoing a training on R  for my research on bioinformatics. They are teaching via Linux and they expect to have it that way. For some packages etc. They said it would be better to use it the international speakers.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but a quick google of `"rstudio" "wsl"` ([one](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049776974-Using-RStudio-Server-in-Windows-WSL2), [two](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-install-rstudio-on-the-wsl-system)), a common theme is that they (RStudio) doesn't support but is suggesting the user of rstudio-server, not rstudio-ide. Just a thought, not necessarily a great answer.

Comment: A few years ago I completely switched to Linux (Ubuntu) for a similar reason, and it is very easy. Since then, I have _never_ missed Windows - on the contrary, Linux has extremely increased my quality of life:)

Comment: I'm having the same blank screen issue under Windows 11 Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2.  I tried also installing RStudio daily and RStudio Electron daily.  Electron came up with the correct 4-panel screen but would not accept any input.  I've also tried running rstudio --no-sandbox.  All other GUI apps are working fine.